# How do I withdraw from an address

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, wallet, sending

I made a Crypto purchase from Shapeshift yesterday, which was fulfilled by one of their partners called BANXA. I just received an email saying "Your order has been fulfilled and you will receive your bitcoin shortly in the address provided" with a link opening to Block explorer. With a QR code and two buttons "Payment request" and "Donation". And a Bech32 (P2WPKH) 42 Alphanumerical code that I got no clue how to use.

I have contacted their support. Opened wallets in Portis, Electrum, Blockchain and Coinomi but with no idea how to receive that 42 code to one of my wallets. How do I get it to move?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

When you set up a trade on Shapeshift, you presumably pick which currency you wish to purchase, and what currency you pay with. You would then provide your withdrawal address to be credited in the purchase. Given that you have received an email that tells you that your purchase went through, I would expect that the bitcoin were sent to the bitcoin address that you provided when you set up the purchase. Check whichever wallet you copied your address from.

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I withdraw from an address**

You don't.

You can withdraw cash, denominated in a currency such as Bitcoin, from an account you have as a customer of an official or unofficial financial institution like a bank, currency-exchange or financial-trading broker etc. You can arrange that the withdrawn amount be paid to a Bitcoin "address" you previously obtained from a Bitcoin wallet you already had.

---

> **a Bech32 (P2WPKH) 42 Alphanumerical code that I got no clue how to use.**

Yes a Bech32 address is a type of Bitcoin address that can have 42 characters.

It is the sort of address that you can get your Bitcoin wallet to create, typically by clicking on a "Receive" button or similar.

If you didn't create that Bech32 Bitcoin address from a wallet you own, prior to arranging the withdrawal of money from the exchange, then the money wasn't paid to you.

---

> **fulfilled by one of their partners called BANXA.**

I'm not familiar with Shapeshift and Banxa but it appears that Banxa is a kind of payment processor that can receive fiat payment, exchange fiat for Bitcoin and pay that Bitcoin amount to a provided Bitcoin address. I don't know what value is provided by Shapeshift here but that probably doesn't matter.

Banxa's [website](https://banxa.com/simple-integration/#), worded for potential partner businesses, says

> The customer enters the amount they’d wish to purchase, in either fiat or crypto. The customers enters their email address and mobile. By default, the customer’s wallet is set to your business’s wallet.

So it is possible that instead of paying into a normal Bitcoin wallet you previsouly set up, you left the default "wallet" and Banxa paid your money to Shapeshift. If this is true, you probably have a "custodial-wallet" (the least safe kind) where someone else (e.g. Shapeshift) is looking after your money for you and you just have a kind of IOU. As far as the Bitcoin network is concerned that money belongs to Shapeshift not to you. You should be able to log in to Shapeshift and see if you have an account with a non-zero balance.